# What is the standard default localization of ostream?

Tags: c++, localization, std

I am using CLang 8.0 and given this code example:

```
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct slash : std::numpunct<char> {
    char do_decimal_point()   const { return '/'; }  // separate with slash
};

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    auto slash_locale = std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new slash);
    std::locale::global( slash_locale );

    oss << 4.5;
    std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

What I get is "4.5". My question is: is this behaviour of ignoring the locale written in the standard? Because a colleague of mine is using XCode and stating that there "4/5" is being printed. I would like to understand if it is supposed to be implementation defined, or if the standard, in case my collegue states the truth, is being violated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard defines that during construction `basic_stream` base object of  `basic_stringbuf` object is getting initialized with a copy of current global locale and that the results of using that locale will be in effect until member `imbue` is called.

> **30.6.3.1 basic_streambuf constructors [streambuf.cons]**
>   `basic_streambuf();`
>   1 Effects: Constructs an object of class `basic_streambuf<charT, traits>` and initializes:
>   (1.1) all its pointer member objects to null pointers,
>   (1.2) the `getloc()` member to a copy the global locale, `locale()`, at the time of construction.
>   2 Remarks: Once the `getloc()` member is initialized, results of calling locale member functions, and of members of facets so obtained, can safely be cached until the next time the member imbue is called.

So in this case the effects of changing of global locale should be visible only if `oss` is created *after* that change took place.